# Is it possible to change the queryport and port when launching from steamcmd?

Tags: windows, steam

I'm working on a utility tool for my friends to restart my servers remotely(it'll have some extra uses ontop) a friend is working on the front end, I'm working on the backend. Currently I have everything streamlined through python and windows batch files to interact with and start the servers or stop them. The problem I'm running into currently is that for any game where I can't change the queryport from 27015 in an ini for that specific game, I need to be able to do it when launching the server. This is specifically to deal with having multiple servers for a game, such as a modded and vanilla server respectively.

I've tried to pass through the -queryport and -port arguments within steamcmd, but it doesn't seem to take. I can get the result if I use a batch file that starts the .exe, but that doesn't work with what I want to do, unless i redo a large portion of the system to work off of the exes and bypass steamcmd entirely.

an example after logging into steamcmd:

```
app_run 2394010 -queryport 27016 -port 8212
```

If anyone can figure out a way to do this while still using steamcmd, I'd appreciate it.